# How to get RegistrationID using GCM in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to do push notification in android using GCM. I read the Google docs for GCM and their demo application. I created the client side program mentioned here 
`http://android.amolgupta.in/`. But i am not getting registration ID. Also I am not getting some points like:

1. do i need to server program too with this
2. on Google demo app they mention that i need to change api key at "samples/gcm-demo-server/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/api.key" is it necessary to do it every time as i am creating new project

Can any one provide me proper project other than google provided so that i clear my concepts.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

*Here I have written a few steps for How to Get RegID and Notification starting from scratch*

1. Create/Register App on Google Cloud
2. Setup Cloud SDK with Development
3. Configure project for GCM
4. Get Device Registration ID
5. Send Push Notifications
6. Receive Push Notifications

You can find a complete tutorial here:

> [Getting Started with Android Push Notification : Latest Google Cloud
> Messaging (GCM) - step by step complete tutorial](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-google-cloud.html)

[image]

Code snippet to get Registration ID (Device Token for Push Notification).

**Configure project for GCM**

---

## Update AndroidManifest file

To enable GCM in our project we need to add a few permissions to our manifest file. Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and add this code:
Add Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET”/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name=“.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name=“<your_package_name_here>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name=“<your_package_name_here>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Add GCM Broadcast Receiver declaration in your application tag:

```
<application
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" ]]>
            <intent-filter]]>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="" />
            </intent-filter]]>

        </receiver]]>
     
<application/>
```

Add GCM Service declaration

```
<application
     <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
<application/>
```

---

## Get Registration ID (Device Token for Push Notification)

**Now Go to your Launch/Splash Activity**

Add Constants and Class Variables

```
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private final static String TAG = "LaunchActivity";
protected String SENDER_ID = "Your_sender_id";
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm =null;
private String regid = null;
private Context context= null;
```

Update OnCreate and OnResume methods

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices();
}


// # Implement GCM Required methods(Add below methods in LaunchActivity)

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported - Google Play Services.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Registration ID not found.");
        return "";
    }
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.d(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    return getSharedPreferences(LaunchActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}


private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object...params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                Log.d(TAG, "########################################");
                Log.d(TAG, "Current Device's Registration ID is: " + msg);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            //to do here
        };
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

---

**Note** : please store `REGISTRATION_KEY`, it is important for sending PN Message to GCM. Also keep in mind: this key will be unique for all devices and GCM will send Push Notifications by `REGISTRATION_KEY` only.

Comment: once you've generated the REGISTRATION_KEY (presumably on your phone), how do you get that to your server?

Answer (score 5):

In response to your first question: Yes, you have to run a server app to send the messages, as well as a client app to receive them.

In response to your second question: Yes, every application needs its own API key.  This key is for your server app, not the client.

Comment: Ok now i bit confused that how should i create my application on push notification i mean what i need to do on clent side and server side ?

Comment: Your server needs an API key so that the GCM infrastructure will accept messages from it.  Your client needs a RegistrationID from the GCM client library so that your server app knows who to send the message to.  You need to send this RegistrationID to the server.  The tutorials should walk you through this.

Comment: Not specifically, but sure.  Whatever works.  You might want to start with the source code for a complete sample app and refer to it as you walk through the tutorial.

Comment: Ok @Sparky. I tried client code and upload it above. will you please check that one actually it is not showing me any registrationID. where i went wrong exactly?

Comment: @Sparky: I am not getting REGISTRAION OK return for GCM onRegistration, though I am having new registration ID,
would you guess what I am missing

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to get Registration ID using GCM

```
String regId = "", msg = "";

public void getRegisterationID() {

    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object...params) {

            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(Login.this);
                }
                regId = gcm.register(YOUR_SENDER_ID);
                Log.d("in async task", regId);

                // try
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            return msg;
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
 }
```

and don't forget to write permissions in manifest...
I hope it helps!

Comment: Do you allways keep " // TODO Auto-generated method stub" after you implemeted a method?

Comment: no it was just an example code,i write it in hurry... ;)