# Update UI from servvice

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

I've follow this code: [How to get RegistrationID using GCM in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516782/how-to-get-registrationid-using-gcm-in-android)

but i want update the `TextView` of `MainActivity` with received message.
please help me why i don't know how i update a UI from service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use Broadcast receivers here. So `IntentService` will broadcast the event, and all activities or something else can register for it.

To avoid overkill of `BroadcastReceivers` itself (as they are intented to be used in inter-process communication and can be an overkill and security leak) - I reccoment using `LocalBroadcastManager` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html .  It's a helper for strictly-local broadcasts, makes easier to handle them and provide more performance and security.

**Update:**

To use LocalBroadcastReceiver inside GCM IntentService you should do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent bIntent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    bIntent .putExtra("message", intent); //or get some info from Gcm intent and put it into this one.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(bIntent);
}
```

And here you can check how to register the receiver inside your activity, it's pretty easy: [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Good luck

Comment: thanks alexn, i'm newbie of android, please apply the modify to code and show me... sorry for my english.

Comment: Actually, there is even no need to paste a code - the topic is described here with details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager Hope it helps

Comment: but i don't know ho to apply the code why the received extends GCMBaseIntentService.... help me please...

Comment: I'd modified the answer, please check it.

Comment: one moment... but where do i put the code for edit the textview?